# Keep div certain distance from another div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a login box DIV and below that another login button DIV which is 1% margin top from the Login Box DIV.

[image]

The login box div has these styles:

```
.login-box {
height: 39%;
width: 100%;
}

.login-box-wrap {
width: 30%;
height: 98%;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
background-color: #609ac4;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
margin-top: 1%;
min-width: 250px;
max-width: 500px;
max-height: 350px;
min-height: 100px;
}

.logintextbox {
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
border-bottom-color: rgba(176, 221, 245, 1);
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
width: 98%;
height: 32%;
font-size: 1.2em;
font-family: open sans;
color: white;
padding-left: 2%;
}
```

Then when i shrink it alittle more then button overlaps the box like this:

[image]

This is the login button styles:

```
.login-button {
height: 5%;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 1%;
position: fixed;
}


.login-button-wrap {
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
min-width: 250px;
max-width: 500px;
min-height: 20px;
max-height: 31px;
}

#btnLogin {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(#73afda,#609ac4);
border: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
font-family: Arial;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

**How can i keep the button around 10px/1% margin top from the box at all resolutions**

**EDIT: **

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="login-box">
            <div class="login-box-wrap">
                <input id="txt_client_reference" type="text" class="logintextbox" placeholder="Client Reference" />
                <input id="txt_postcode" type="text" class="logintextbox" placeholder="Postcode" />
                <input id="txt_date_of_birth" type="text" class="logintextbox" placeholder="Date of Birth" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="login-button">
            <div class="login-button-wrap">
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Log in" CssClass="loginButton" OnClientClick="checkForm(); valid_postcode()" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Would you post even some html ? thanks

Comment: @FoxNos Added the html

Comment: Ok, then two things: What does <asp> tag stand for ? You want the button to have a constant margin top relative to the box on windows resize ?

Comment: I think if you remove `position:fixed` from your CSS for `.login-button` as that means it stays in the same place all the time

Comment: @FoxNos Yes, So the LoginButton div sould always be around 1% below the LoginBox div.

Comment: @Harry12345 This doesn't work.

Comment: I can't seem to re-create the problem, I have a JS fiddle here which uses your code and there doesn't seem to be a problem with it   - [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cf6oupd7/)

Comment: @Harry12345 What you created is what I need? What did you change as thats perfect.

Comment: All I did was change the `<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Log in" CssClass="loginButton" OnClientClick="checkForm(); valid_postcode()" />` line to `<button ID="btnLogin" value="Login">Login</button>` in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little far off on this one, but you have position fixed there, which doesn't really care about your margin anymore.

Comment: That might be my bad, I added thin to see if it would work and it didn't. I have tried it without and it still didn't work.